# TextMate - auto add closing HTML tag

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to make TextMate automatically add a closing HTML tag when I type the opening one? Something like what Notepad++ does under Windows/Linux, or MS Visual Studio.

I mean WITHOUT any shortcuts? So I just type "<body>" and it adds "</body>" and puts the cursor back in between. Without any "Ctrl + Shift + Option + Whatever" black magic.

Or a TextMate alternative maybe?

PS. Mac OS is just one of the many OS'es I work in, so I don't want to litter my brain with any shortcuts...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't. The simplest thing you could do for closing tags is to type some opening tag with it's contents `<div>Some text` and then hit `Command + Option + Dot` to close the most recent unclosed tag. This involves a shortcut but it is easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Typing e.g. `body` and then pressing TAB will complete the tag.

Comment: This will not work for all tags though because it requires a separate snippet for each tag

Comment: I know, but it's still better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative, which may or may not suit how you code, is to hit ctrl+shift+W (wrap selection). With nothing selected you'll get `<p></p>`, with the 'p' highlighted so you can overtype with your desired tag name.

I personally prefer the cmd+option+. shortcut already mentioned.

Credit to http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200811/textmate_productivity_tips/